# How can I translate "rotated" in French in a single word using the root "rotation" ?

Tags: traduction, morphologie

Rotaté? Rotationné? Can it even be transformed into an adjective in French?
I will take any suggestion, even from Latin or Old French.

Comment: Please provide the context and/or phrase/sentence. _L'objet auquel on a fait faire une rotation, ayant ainsi fait cette rotation, est probablement « rotated »_.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no French verb or adjective with a root connected to the English "rotate." This word came to English straight from Latin: [*rotatus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rotate).

Since you didn't offer a context, it's impossible to know which of these French translations might be appropriate:

- *tourné*
- *pivoté*
- *alterné*